# Use the Triangle Inequality, and other properties of modulus, to show that:

Tags: calculus, inequality

(a) If $|a|\le 1$ then $|3+a^3|\le 4$.

(b) If $|a|\le 1/2$ and $|b|\le 1/4$ then $|4a^4+2b^2|\le 3/8$.

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: I have tried showing (a) using the triangle method but I have ended up with |a^3+3|≤|a^3|+|3| and don't know where to go forward from there.

Comment: It's advisable to include your attempt in your post.

Comment: Together with the triangle inequality use the fact that $|x^n|=|x|^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$|a^3+3| \le |a^3|+3 = |a|^3 +3$$

If we have  $|a|\le 1$, then $|a|^3 \le 1$. Now you should be able to make conclusion for the first part.